# Strange behavior with the lisp random function

Tags: random, common-lisp

Is there anyone can explain to me the following behavior concerning the random function with the float numbers and how to get rid of this:

```
CL-USER> (loop for i from 1 to 20 collect (* 0.1 (random 100)))        

;; with sbcl ...
(9.2 4.4 9.5 0.5 9.7 5.8 4.3 9.900001 3.7 6.8 2.6000001 9.5 1.6 8.900001 3.3 1.7 5.1 5.5 4.2000003 8.2)

;; with closure ...
(7.7000003 7.2000003 1.7 5.6 7.5 2.2 5.0 7.6 2.0 4.9 2.9 1.6 0.4 6.1 3.3 7.1 8.7 6.5 5.6 9.2)
```

Comment: What behavior do you want to get rid of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is totally expected and appropriate in the context of floating point numbers.  It is the same in every other language.

Binary floating point numbers (as defined by IEEE) cannot represent all decimal fractions exactly.  For example, the decimal fraction `0.2` in binary is `0.0011001100110011....`, so you cannot represent it exactly with a finite amount of bits.  Therefore, many floating point numbers necessarily are rounded.  If you add them up then, the rounding errors accumulate.  Sometimes they cancel each other out, sometimes not.  If you multiply them (as you did), they multiply.

If you want to have the exact fractions, Common Lisp offers you to work with *rationals*.  For example, if you calculate `(/ 1 5)`, you get `1/5`, which is the printed representation of such a rational number, and this is exact (internally, the calculation works on the numerator and denominator).  You can calculate with these exact numbers:

```
CL-USER> (+ 1/5 2/3)
13/15

CL-USER> (+ 3/5 2/5)
1
```

In order to *print them out* as decimal fractions, you can use the format control [`~f`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw445/CLHS/Body/22_cca.htm), for example:

```
CL-USER> (format t "~,3f" 13/15)
0.867
```

Answer (score 1):

What's the strange behavior?

Are you worried that, for example, 0.1 * 99 seems to be 9.90001? That's normal for floating point numbers. They're inexact. They sacrifice exactness to get range. You cannot expect to get something without giving something up.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `rational` numbers, don't use floats...

```
(loop for i from 1 to 20 collect (/ (random 100) 10))
```

Comment: To get the appropriate behavior, I did:  `(loop for i from 1 to 20 collect (/ (random 100) 10.0))`  in this case we still use floats, but we get the expected result ...  This behavior is not clear for me.

Comment: @user3224092: No, this does not do what you think.  You still have rounding errors, you just do not multiply them, so they keep below the threshold of your printed representation.

Answer (score 0):

```
(loop for i from 1 to 20 collect (read-from-string (format nil "~v$" 1 (/ (random 100) 10))))
```